# Switch to popup within same window

Tags: python, selenium

Writing selenium automation in chrome, how can I handle popup with appearing in the same window see the screenshot?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgsSg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Is it OS dialog or browser? If it is a browser popup, you can try handling it as an alert. By switching to it using driver.switchTo().alert and then sendkeys and accept/decline alert.

Comment: That wasn't a JS _Alert_ to be handled through `driver.switchTo().alert`.

Comment: Well he has not mentioned it. That is why i am asking

Comment: Agree, _OP hasn't mentioned it_